# no method error using Datavector at LightTable Julia0.3

Tags: julia, lighttable

LiteTable 0.6.7
Julia 0.3
Jewel0.6.4
June 0.2
Mac OSX 10.9

Hi,I have a problem at using Datavector by DataFrame package.

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame()
df["Name"] = DataVector["JohnSmith", "JaneDoe"]
df["Height"] = DataVector[73.0,68.0]
df["Weight"] = DataVector[NA,130]
df["Gender"] = DataVector["Male","Female"]
```

after that, julia says

```
no method convert(Type{DataArray{T,1}}, ASCIIString)
in getindex at array.jl:121
```

I could do this same script at julia 0.2
Does LightTable's plugin such as Jewel,June not accept this DataFrames function?

I tried dataeye() and other function ,but this doesn't work..

Brw, I found a similar post at google group. 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/VmgmRnBCo9I

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're reading very old documentation for DataArrays and DataFrames. You might want to look at more recent docs: http://juliastats.github.io/DataFrames.jl/

Here's how'd you do what you're trying to do:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame()
df[:Name] = @data(["JohnSmith", "JaneDoe"])
df[:Height] = @data([73.0,68.0])
df[:Weight] = @data([NA,130])
df[:Gender] = @data(["Male","Female"])
```

Comment: Thanks John,I had watched your video. I didnt know this is very old. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRClA5YLiIc  I tried your advise and everything going well now. thanks.

Comment: The link in this answer is dead. Documentation can now be found [here](http://dataframesjl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).